# Enable Docker Bearer Token Realm as generally outlined in Realms

Tags: docker, devops, nexus, nexus3

As per the Nexus 3.x docx, "You also need to enable the Docker Bearer Token Realm as generally outlined in Realms. This realm is inactive by default"

Does anyone know how to make this bearer token active?

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/docker-registry/docker-authentication

Answer (score 2):

*Note just in case*: the docker bearer token was added in [nexus 3.6.0 in 2017](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/release-notes/2017-release-notes#id-2017ReleaseNotes-RepositoryManager3.6.0) and will not be available if your are running an older version. Anyhow, I strongly suggest to run an up-to-date version of nexus.

---

Once logged in nexus with an admin account, 5 easy steps illustrated in the below screenshot:

1. click on the server administration gear on top
2. select security > realms on the left menu
3. select Docker Bearer Token Realm in the list of available realms
4. click the right arrow to pass it to the active side
5. save
   [image]

Comment: I don't see that Docker Bearer Token option.

Comment: Which version of nexus are you running?

Comment: FYI, this option was added in [Nexus 3.6.0 in 2017](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/release-notes/2017-release-notes#id-2017ReleaseNotes-RepositoryManager3.6.0). If you are running an older version, you have to upgrade to have this option available (and more generally for security reasons).

Comment: +1 (esp emphazing the date release).  The docs linked are for the most recent version which is 3.27.0 at time of this comment.  If you're using 3.5.0 or before, you're over 3 years old.